# jQuery select option skip option group keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make this custom select with jQuery and CSS work with the keyboard arrows, but I'm having some issues. When there is an option group, the next option isn't being selected.

I belive the problem is happening in the following line of code, as it can't find the next option but if you select one of the options inside an option group, you can select the next one until you hit another option group:

```
// Down
} else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
  if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
    $dropdown.trigger('click');
  } else {
// In this line here, it can't find the next option
    var $next = $focused_option.nextAll('.option:not(.disabled)').first();
    if ($next.length > 0) {
      $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
      $next.addClass('focus');
    }...// Rest of the key listeners
```

Here's the full code:

```js
/*  jQuery Nice Select - v1.1.0
    https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select
    Made by Hernán Sartorio  
  
    Customized by: Hugo Borges
                   Marco Messa
*/
(function ($) {
    $.fn.niceSelect = function (method) {
        
        // Methods
        if (typeof method === 'string') {
            if (method === 'update') {
                this.each(function () {
                    var $select = $(this);
                    var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');
                    var open = $dropdown.hasClass('open');
                    var focused = $select.parents('.form-group-select').hasClass('focused');

                    if ($dropdown.length) {
                        $dropdown.remove();
                        create_nice_select($select);

                        if (open) {
                            $select.next().trigger('click');
                        } else if (focused) {
                            $select.parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused');
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else if (method === 'destroy') {
                this.each(function () {
                    var $select = $(this);
                    var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');

                    if ($dropdown.length) {
                        $dropdown.remove();
                        $select.css('display', '');
                    }
                });
                if ($('.nice-select').length === 0) {
                    $(document).off('.nice_select');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Method "' + method + '" does not exist.');
            }
            return this;
        }

        // Hide native select
        this.hide();

        // Create custom markup
        this.each(function () {
            var $select = $(this);

            if (!$select.next().hasClass('nice-select')) {
                create_nice_select($select);
            }
        });

        function create_nice_select($select) {
            $select.after($('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('nice-select')
                    .addClass($select.attr('class') || '')
                    .addClass($select.attr('disabled') ? 'disabled' : '')
                    .attr('tabindex', $select.attr('disabled') ? null : '0')
                    .html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>')
                    );

            var $dropdown = $select.next();
            var $options = $select.find('option');
            var $optgroups = $select.find('optgroup');
            var $selected = $select.find('option:selected');

            $dropdown.find('.current').html($selected.data('display') || $selected.text());

            $options.each(function () {
                var $option = $(this);
                var display = $option.data('display');
                var group = $option.parents('optgroup').data('i');

                $dropdown.find('ul').append($('<li></li>')
                        .attr('data-value', $option.val())
                        .attr('data-display', (display || null))
                        .attr('data-group', (group || null))
                        .addClass('option' +
                                ($option.is(':selected') ? ' selected' : '') +
                                ($option.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : ''))
                        .html($option.text())
                        );
            });
            $optgroups.each(function(i, g) {
              label = $(g).attr('label');
              $dropdown.find('ul li').filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('group') === $(g).data('i');
              })
              .wrapAll('<div class="optgroup"/>')
              .parent()
              .prepend('<span class="label">' + label + '</span>');
            });
        }

        /* Event listeners */
        // Unbind existing events in case that the plugin has been initialized before
        $(document).off('.nice_select');

        // Open/close
        $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select', function () {
            var $dropdown = $(this);

            $('.nice-select').not($dropdown).removeClass('open');
            $dropdown.toggleClass('open');

            if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                $dropdown.find('.option');
                $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
                $dropdown.find('.selected').addClass('focus');
            } else {
                $dropdown.focus();
            }
        });

        // Close when clicking outside
        $(document).on('click.nice_select', function (event) {

            if ($(event.target).closest('.nice-select').length === 0) {
                $('.nice-select').removeClass('open').find('.option');
            }
        });

        // Animation loading a page
        $('select').on('blur', function (e) {
            $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
        }).trigger('blur');

        // Option click
        $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select .option:not(.disabled)', function () {

            var $option = $(this);
            var $dropdown = $option.closest('.nice-select');

            $dropdown.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $option.addClass('selected');

            var text = $option.data('display') || $option.text();
            $dropdown.find('.current').text(text);

            $dropdown.prev('select').val($option.data('value')).trigger('change');

            // Animation
            $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', ($option.data('value') !== ''));
        });

        // Keyboard events
        $(document).on('keydown.nice_select', '.nice-select', function (event) {
            
            console.log(event.keyCode);

            var $dropdown = $(this);
            var $focused_option = $($dropdown.find('.focus') || $dropdown.find('.list .option.selected'));

            // Space or Enter
            if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
                if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                    $focused_option.trigger('click');
                } else {
                    $dropdown.trigger('click');
                }
                return false;

                // Down
            } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
                if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                    $dropdown.trigger('click');
                } else {
                    var $next = $focused_option.nextAll('.option:not(.disabled)').first();
                    if ($next.length > 0) {
                        $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
                        $next.addClass('focus');
                    }
                }
                return false;

                // Up
            } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
                if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                    $dropdown.trigger('click');
                } else {
                    var $prev = $focused_option.prevAll('.option:not(.disabled)').first();
                    if ($prev.length > 0) {
                        $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
                        $prev.addClass('focus');
                    }
                }
                return false;

                // Esc
            } else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                    $dropdown.trigger('click');
                }

                // Tab
            } else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
                if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('select').niceSelect();
```

```css
.control-label {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}
.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.form-group-select {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.nice-select:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #0091FF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}
.nice-select.open::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.nice-select {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.nice-select span {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.optgroup span {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.nice-select:hover, .nice-select:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.nice-select:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #484848;
    border-right: 2px solid #484848;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
    transform-origin: 66% 66%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    width: 5px;
}
.nice-select.open:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.nice-select.open .list {
    color: #484848;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}
.nice-select.disabled {
    border-color: #ededed;
    color: #999;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.nice-select.disabled:after {
    border-color: #cccccc;
}
.nice-select .list {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
.nice-select .list:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.nice-select .list:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
.nice-select .option {
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    min-height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 7px solid #FFF;
}
.nice-select .option:hover, .nice-select .focus {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-left: 7px solid #F65314;
}
.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent !important;
}
.nice-select .option.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nice-select .option.disabled {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #999;
    cursor: default;
}
.no-csspointerevents .nice-select .list {
    display: none;
}
.no-csspointerevents .nice-select.open .list {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<div class='form-group-select'>
  <label class='control-label'>SIM?</label>
  <select name='gostou'>
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label='PRODUTOS' data-i="1">
      <option value="s">SIM</option>
      <option value="n">NÃO</option>
      <optgroup label='PRODUTOS' data-i="2">
        <option value="s">SIM</option>
        <option value="n">NÃO</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.nextAll()` only finds siblings. When you group your options into nested DIVs to match the option groups, only the options in the same level of the same option group will be siblings.

Rather than using `.nextAll()`, get a collection of all the options, find the current element's index in the collection, then increment that index to find the next option.

```
var $all_options = $dropdown.find(".option:not(.disabled)");
var $next = $all_options.eq($all_options.index($focused_option) + 1);
```

```js
/*  jQuery Nice Select - v1.1.0
    https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select
    Made by Hernán Sartorio  
  
    Customized by: Hugo Borges
                   Marco Messa
*/
(function($) {
  $.fn.niceSelect = function(method) {

    // Methods
    if (typeof method === 'string') {
      if (method === 'update') {
        this.each(function() {
          var $select = $(this);
          var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');
          var open = $dropdown.hasClass('open');
          var focused = $select.parents('.form-group-select').hasClass('focused');

          if ($dropdown.length) {
            $dropdown.remove();
            create_nice_select($select);

            if (open) {
              $select.next().trigger('click');
            } else if (focused) {
              $select.parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused');
            }
          }
        });
      } else if (method === 'destroy') {
        this.each(function() {
          var $select = $(this);
          var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');

          if ($dropdown.length) {
            $dropdown.remove();
            $select.css('display', '');
          }
        });
        if ($('.nice-select').length === 0) {
          $(document).off('.nice_select');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Method "' + method + '" does not exist.');
      }
      return this;
    }

    // Hide native select
    this.hide();

    // Create custom markup
    this.each(function() {
      var $select = $(this);

      if (!$select.next().hasClass('nice-select')) {
        create_nice_select($select);
      }
    });

    function create_nice_select($select) {
      $select.after($('<div></div>')
        .addClass('nice-select')
        .addClass($select.attr('class') || '')
        .addClass($select.attr('disabled') ? 'disabled' : '')
        .attr('tabindex', $select.attr('disabled') ? null : '0')
        .html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>')
      );

      var $dropdown = $select.next();
      var $options = $select.find('option');
      var $optgroups = $select.find('optgroup');
      var $selected = $select.find('option:selected');

      $dropdown.find('.current').html($selected.data('display') || $selected.text());

      $options.each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        var display = $option.data('display');
        var group = $option.parents('optgroup').data('i');

        $dropdown.find('ul').append($('<li></li>')
          .attr('data-value', $option.val())
          .attr('data-display', (display || null))
          .attr('data-group', (group || null))
          .addClass('option' +
            ($option.is(':selected') ? ' selected' : '') +
            ($option.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : ''))
          .html($option.text())
        );
      });
      $optgroups.each(function(i, g) {
        label = $(g).attr('label');
        $dropdown.find('ul li').filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('group') === $(g).data('i');
          })
          .wrapAll('<div class="optgroup"/>')
          .parent()
          .prepend('<span class="label">' + label + '</span>');
      });
    }

    /* Event listeners */
    // Unbind existing events in case that the plugin has been initialized before
    $(document).off('.nice_select');

    // Open/close
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select', function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);

      $('.nice-select').not($dropdown).removeClass('open');
      $dropdown.toggleClass('open');

      if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
        $dropdown.find('.option');
        $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
        $dropdown.find('.selected').addClass('focus');
      } else {
        $dropdown.focus();
      }
    });

    // Close when clicking outside
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', function(event) {

      if ($(event.target).closest('.nice-select').length === 0) {
        $('.nice-select').removeClass('open').find('.option');
      }
    });

    // Animation loading a page
    $('select').on('blur', function(e) {
      $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
    }).trigger('blur');

    // Option click
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select .option:not(.disabled)', function() {

      var $option = $(this);
      var $dropdown = $option.closest('.nice-select');

      $dropdown.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $option.addClass('selected');

      var text = $option.data('display') || $option.text();
      $dropdown.find('.current').text(text);

      $dropdown.prev('select').val($option.data('value')).trigger('change');

      // Animation
      $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', ($option.data('value') !== ''));
    });

    // Keyboard events
    $(document).on('keydown.nice_select', '.nice-select', function(event) {

      console.log(event.keyCode);

      var $dropdown = $(this);
      var $focused_option = $($dropdown.find('.focus') || $dropdown.find('.list .option.selected'));

      // Space or Enter
      if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $focused_option.trigger('click');
        } else {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        }
        return false;

        // Down
      } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        } else {
          var $all_options = $dropdown.find(".option:not(.disabled)");
          var $next = $all_options.eq($all_options.index($focused_option) + 1);
          if ($next.length > 0) {
            $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
            $next.addClass('focus');
          }
        }
        return false;

        // Up
      } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        } else {
          var $all_options = $dropdown.find(".option:not(.disabled)");
          var $prev = $all_options.eq($all_options.index($focused_option) - 1);
          if ($prev.length > 0) {
            $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
            $prev.addClass('focus');
          }
        }
        return false;

        // Esc
      } else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        }

        // Tab
      } else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
$('select').niceSelect();
```

```css
.control-label {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}

.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form-group-select {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}

.nice-select:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}

.nice-select.open::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.nice-select {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nice-select span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.optgroup span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.nice-select:hover,
.nice-select:focus {
  border-color: #0091FF;
}

.nice-select:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #484848;
  border-right: 2px solid #484848;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 5px;
}

.nice-select.open:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.nice-select.open .list {
  color: #484848;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}

.nice-select.disabled {
  border-color: #ededed;
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nice-select.disabled:after {
  border-color: #cccccc;
}

.nice-select .list {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nice-select .list:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.nice-select .list:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

.nice-select .option {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 29px;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 7px solid #FFF;
}

.nice-select .option:hover,
.nice-select .focus {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-left: 7px solid #F65314;
}

.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent !important;
}

.nice-select .option.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nice-select .option.disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999;
  cursor: default;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select .list {
  display: none;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select.open .list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class='form-group-select'>
  <label class='control-label'>SIM?</label>
  <select name='gostou'>
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label='PRODUTOS' data-i="1">
      <option value="s">SIM</option>
      <option value="n">NÃO</option>
      <optgroup label='PRODUTOS' data-i="2">
        <option value="s">SIM</option>
        <option value="n">NÃO</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm can't make it work, should I retrieve all the options inside my key event or before they happen? Because I tried with the code I posted and it's returning only the same option...

Comment: I didn't realize you were working with the DIVs rather than the `<select>` and `<option>`. I've fixed the code. BTW, have you checked out the Select2 plugin, maybe it does what you need?